# Create UILabel at TopLeft of UIVIew and animate straight downwards?

Tags: swift

Iv been working on this new game for a couple months now and run into a problems I cant figure out!

So basically I am creating a "status section" in the top right of my `UIViewController`. In this "status section" will appear `UILabels` that hold status updates as `Strings`. These `UILabels` will appear at the very top left of the `UIView` and will go slowly downwards and lose `Alpha` at the same time..eventually dissappearing once it reaches the bottom.

What Iv Done?

So as you can see in the code before so far Iv been able to create the `UILabel` at random locations but for some reason the `UILabels` spawn off screen.

[image]

Code

```
func createStatus() {


        let viewWidth = self.statusView.frame.width
        let viewHeight = self.statusView.frame.width

        let randomX = CGFloat(viewWidth / 2)
        let randomY = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(viewHeight)) + 50)


        let frame = self.statusView.frame.origin

        let status = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(viewWidth / 4) - 20, y: CGFloat(viewHeight - viewHeight) + 10), size: CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 50.0)))

        status.text = "This is a status"
        status.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        status.alpha = 1
        self.statusView.addSubview(status)
        print("Status made")
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2) {
            status.center = frame
            status.alpha = 0

        }

    }
```

Iv added an image of the problem and the `UIView`statusView as well. Im having trouble making the UILabel at the top left and i'v tried this code below and it doesnt even "spawn" the UILabel on the screen.

```
let frame = self.statusView.frame.origin
CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func createStatus() {


    let viewWidth = self.statusView.frame.width
    let viewHeight = self.statusView.frame.width

    //Why are these here?
    let randomX = CGFloat(viewWidth / 2)
    let randomY = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(viewHeight)) + 50)


    let origin = CGPointZero//Origins are relative to superview, so top left would be (0, 0)

    //Renamed status to statusLabel so that we know its a label and not a model object
    let statusLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: origin, size: CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 50.0)))

    statusLabel.text = "This is a status"
    statusLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    statusLabel.alpha = 1
    self.statusView.addSubview(statusLabel)
    print("Status made")
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2) {
        //Animate the origin instead of center position. 
        //The origin will be the height of the statusView - the height of your label. x stays 0 to keep it along left edge.
        statusLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.statusView.frame.height - statusLabel.frame.height )
        statusLabel.alpha = 0

    }, { (completed) in
        if completed {
           //If statusLabel doesn't have a superView it will be dealloc after the function goes out of scope. So remove it from superview after animaion is complete and ARC takes care of it.
           statusLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Also would it be a good idea to delete the UILabel's this creates? On average each user may press this button 1,000 + times.... easily.. If so how should I make sure to delete them so my memory is managed?

Comment: Your a legend! I need to get as good as you mate thanks for the help :). As far as the completion block I am getthing this error - http://i.imgur.com/HhI6AS2.png